# How to use customised values.yaml in Fluxcd helm?

Tags: fluxcd

I installed Fluxcd in Kubernetes using Helm. Everything is working good as when I commit changes to gitlab it will auto deploy the changes to the helm release.

The helm chart I used for kibana is from the official chart but I made some changes to the default values.yaml file to cater for my project. I deployed my edited values.yaml file to my gitlab and specify the HelmRelease to use customised values.yaml using `externalSourceRef`.

I tried with editing the values and commit in gitlab. It does upgraded the helm revision but the values is not changing. Is this the correct way to install service using official chart but use our own customised values.yaml file ? Or is there any better way ?

```
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: demo
  annotations:
    fluxcd.io/automated: "true"
spec:
  releaseName: kibana
  chart:
    repository: https://helm.elastic.co
    version: 7.9.1
    name: kibana
  valuesFrom:
  - externalSourceRef:
    # URL of the values.yaml
    url: https://....../-/raw/master/releases/kibana-values.yaml
    optional: true
```